# Establishing a sip proxy server on PC with Android clients

Tags: android, sip, rtp

I have implemented a sip based real time voice transfer under the impression that two of my phones on the same WIFI network can communicate provided that they have each others IP addresses. However, I could not make it work... I am using rtp to transfer voice between these clients. 
Also, it's come to my notice that using a PC on the WIFI network as server is better. Now, can I use this PC as a proxy server to establish a sip end to end connection? If yes, how?

Are there existing implementations for initializing a session? Specifically, if someone could give me an example on what address/ports I would need both of my clients to establish the connection to, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have implemented correctly all the necessary parts that SIP protocol demands, then you have to install a SIP server on your PC and just create two accounts that the phones will connect with them on the server. I have tried with Android the Asterisk server, but I am sure that there will be many others out there...

By default SIP servers are listening on port 5060 using UDP. This port is used only for the initiation of the session (and other control messages) and **NOT** for the transfer of RTP packets.

Comment: for ex: The code for sip demo in android developers site, ask for a domain before setup, would this domain be the ip address of my laptop , say 192.168.2.10:5060 ? for the second client , should it be the same domain ?

Comment: Yes exactly. But on the laptop you have to run a SIP server and to set up two accounts for the phones. Unfortunately I haven't played with the SIP demo of Android samples to help you better...

Comment: To future people : use an online sip service provider as the domain... I need to get the best answer for this question ...